# Bootstrap icon set auto-resizing too small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Found a solution that auto centered my icons *(horizontally & vertically)* within the container.

But now when viewport is smartphone size, the icons resize very small and the container resizes too large.

```
   <section id="icon">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3">
          <a href="https://github.com/RyanGarant"><img class="img-responsive" alt="github" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25231.svg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
           <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6502003/ryan-garant"><img alt="stackoverflow" src="http://ryangarant.com/stacko.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
         <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ryantgarant"><img alt="linkedin" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145807.svg"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

    /*Icon Section*/
#icon .col-xs-2 {
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}
#icon .container-fluid {
  background: white;
}
#icon img {
  height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;
}
```

***What are the best practices for keeping icons proportional within its parent container?***

Comment: You limit the column is col-xs-2, is the icon smaller than the container itself?
Besides, you can make the display of <a> is block. See if it helps

Comment: @ToanLu  Thanks!!!

Comment: Does it mean your problem resolved?

Comment: Can you share your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FontAwesome icons did the trick :)

http://fontawesome.io/

[image]